# Output HTML From getRawContent() Imap - Zend Mail

Tags: vue.js, gmail, imap, zend-mail

So Im using ZEND MAIL to do an IMAP connection to Gmail to get Emails

So I have

```
$emailContent = $mail->getRawContent($id);
```

Which gets me content that looks like so

```
"--000000000000fe4838056bb3f88c\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n The best of Gmail, wherever you are\r\n[image: Google]\r\n[image: Nexus 4 with Gmail]\r\n\r\nHi Genius\r\n\r\n\r\nGet the official Gmail app\r\n\r\nThe best features of Gmail are only available on your phone and tablet with\r\nthe official Gmail app. Download the app or go to gmail.com\r\n<https://www.gmail.com/> on your computer or mobile device to get started.\r\n\r\n[image: Google Play]\r\n<https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=3Dcom.google.android.gm>  [i=\r\nmage:\r\nApp Store] <https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/gmail/id422689480?mt=3D8>\r\n\r\n\r\n[image: Gmail icon] Happy emailing,\r\nThe Gmail Team\r\n=C2=A9 2018 Google Inc. 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043\r\n\r\n--000000000000fe4838056bb3f88c\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html><head><meta http-equiv=3D\"content-type\" content=3D\"text/html;charset=\r\n=3DUTF-8\"/><title>The best of Gmail, wherever you are</title></head><body s=\r\ntyle=3D\"background-color:#e5e5e5; margin:20px 0;\"><br/><div style=3D\"margin=\r\n:2%;\"><div style=3D\"direction:ltr; text-align:left; font-family:'Open sans'=\r\n,'Arial',sans-serif; color:#444; background-color:white; padding:1.5em; bor=\r\nder-radius:1em; box-shadow:1px -5px 8px 2px #bbb; max-width:580px; margin:2=\r\n% auto 0 auto;\"><table style=3D\"background:white;width:100%\"><tr><td><div s=\r\ntyle=3D\"width:90px; height:54px; margin:10px auto;\"><img src=3D\"https://ser=\r\nvices.google.com/fh/files/emails/google_logo_flat_90_color.png\" alt=3D\"Goog=\r\nle\" width=3D\"90\" height=3D\"34\"/></div><div style=3D\"float:right; padding-to=\r\np:2em;\"><img src=3D\"https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/services/mail/msa/welc=\r\nome_nexus.png\" alt=3D\"Nexus 4 with Gmail\" style=3D\"border:0; margin-right:1=\r\n0px;\" width=3D\"155\" height=3D\"242\"/></div><div style=3D\"width:90%; padding-=\r\nbottom:10px; padding-left:15px\"><p><img alt=3D\"\" aria-hidden=3D\"true\" src=\r\n=3D\"https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/gmail_logo_large.png\" s=\r\ntyle=3D\"display:inline-block; max-height:10px; margin-right:5px;\"/><span st=\r\nyle=3D\"font-family:'Open sans','Arial',sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-s=\r\nize:small; line-height:1.4em\">Hi Genius</span></p><p><span style=3D\"font-fa=\r\nmily:'Open sans','Arial',sans-serif; font-size:2.08em;\"><br/>Get the offici=\r\nal Gmail app</span><br/></p></div><p></p><div style=3D\"padding-left:15px\"><=\r\np style=3D\"size:small; line-height:1.4em;\">The best features of Gmail are o=\r\nnly available on your phone and tablet with the official Gmail app. Downloa=\r\nd the app or go to <a href=3D\"https://www.gmail.com/\" target=3D\"_blank\" sty=\r\nle=3D\"text-decoration:none; color:#15C\">gmail.com</a> on your computer or m=\r\nobile device to get started.</p><p style=3D\"line-height:2em; margin-right:1=\r\n70px;\"><a href=3D\"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=3Dcom.googl=\r\ne.android.gm\" style=3D\"text-decoration:none\"><img alt=3D\"Google Play\" width=\r\n=3D\"127\" height=3D\"44\" src=3D\"https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/services/mai=\r\nl/buttons/google_play_en.png\" style=3D\"border:0\"/></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\r\n=3D\"https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/gmail/id422689480?mt=3D8\" style=3D\"text=\r\n-decoration:none;\"><img alt=3D\"App Store\" width=3D\"144\" height=3D\"43\" src=\r\n=3D\"https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/services/mail/buttons/apple_store_en.p=\r\nng\" style=3D\"border:0\"/></a></p></div><br/><br/>\r\n<div style=3D\"clear:both; padding-left:13px; height:6.8em;\"><table style=3D=\r\n\"width:100%; border-collapse:collapse; border:0\"><tr><td style=3D\"width:68p=\r\nx\"><img alt=3D'Gmail icon' width=3D\"49\" height=3D\"37\" src=3D\"https://ssl.gs=\r\ntatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/gmail_logo_large.png\" style=3D\"display:bl=\r\nock;\"/></td><td style=3D\"align:left; font-family:'Open sans','Arial',sans-s=\r\nerif; vertical-align:bottom\"><span style=3D\"font-size:small\">Happy emailing=\r\n,<br/></span><span style=3D\"font-size:x-large; line-height:1\">The Gmail Tea=\r\nm</span></td></tr></table></div>\r\n</td></tr></table></div>\r\n<div style=3D\"direction:ltr;color:#777; font-size:0.8em; border-radius:1em;=\r\n padding:1em; margin:0 auto 4% auto; font-family:'Arial','Helvetica',sans-s=\r\nerif; text-align:center;\">=C2=A9 2018 Google Inc. 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway=\r\n, Mountain View, CA 94043<br/></div></div></body></html>\r\n\r\n--000000000000fe4838056bb3f88c--"
```

I need to find the best way to output just the message it self

Im using VUE js on the front end and at the moment can just out put the HTML tags